# Doctrine persisting Many-To-One entities

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, cascade, many-to-one, zend-framework3

I'm using Zend Framework 3 with Doctrine and I'm trying to save an Entity "Cidade" related to another Entity "Estado" witch is already stored in the database. However, Doctrine is trying to persist Entity "Estado", and the only attribute I have from Estado is the primary key in a HTML combo.

My view forms are built under Zend forms and fieldsets, which means POST data is automatically converted to the target entities using ClassMethods hydrator.

The problem is that if I set the attribute `$estado` with `cascade={"persist"}` in Cidade Entity, Doctrine tries to persist Estado Entity missing all required attributes but the primary key ID, which comes from POST request (HTML combo). I also considered using `cascade={"detach"}` ir order to Doctrine ignore Estado Entity in the EntityManager. But I get this error:

> *A new entity was found through the relationship 'Application\Entity\Cidade#estado' that was not configured to cascade persist operations for entity: Application\Entity\Estado@000000007598ee720000000027904e61.*

I found a similar doubt [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7709293/doctrine-cascade-options-for-onetomany/11168501) and the only way I could find for this matter was first retrieving Estado Entity and setting it on Cidade Entity before saving. If this is the only way, can I tell my form structure won't work unless I retrieve all relationships before saving the dependant entities?
In other words, what is the best way of doing such thing in Doctrine (for example):

```
<?php
    /*I'm simulating the creation of Estado Entity representing an
    existing Estado in database, so "3" is the ID rendered in HTML combo*/
    $estado = new Entity\Estado();
    $estado->setId(3);

    $cidade = new Entity\Cidade();
    $cidade->setNome("City Test");

    $cidade->setEstado($estado); //relationship here

    $entityManager->persist($cidade);
    $entityManager->flush();
```

How to do that without having to retrieve an Estado all the time I need to save a Cidade? Wouldn't affect performance?

My Cidade Entity:

```
<?php

     namespace Application\Entity;

     use Zend\InputFilter\Factory;
     use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilterInterface;
     use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

     /**
      * Class Cidade
      * @package Application\Entity
      * @ORM\Entity
      */
     class Cidade extends AbstractEntity
     {
         /**
          * @var string
          * @ORM\Column(length=50)
          */
         private $nome;

         /**
          * @var Estado
          * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Estado", cascade={"detach"})
          * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_estado", referencedColumnName="id")
          */
         private $estado;

         /**
          * Retrieve input filter
          *
          * @return InputFilterInterface
          */
         public function getInputFilter()
         {
             if (!$this->inputFilter) {
                 $factory = new Factory();
                 $this->inputFilter = $factory->createInputFilter([
                     "nome" => ["required" => true]
                 ]);
             }
             return $this->inputFilter;
         }

         /**
          * @return string
          */
         public function getNome()
         {
             return $this->nome;
         }

         /**
          * @param string $nome
          */
         public function setNome($nome)
         {
             $this->nome = $nome;
         }

         /**
          * @return Estado
          */
         public function getEstado()
         {
             return $this->estado;
         }

         /**
          * @param Estado $estado
          */
         public function setEstado($estado)
         {
             $this->estado = $estado;
         }
     }
```

My Estado Entity:

```
<?php

    namespace Application\Entity;

    use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
    use Zend\InputFilter\Factory;
    use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilterInterface;

    /**
     * Class Estado
     * @package Application\Entity
     * @ORM\Entity
     */
    class Estado extends AbstractEntity
    {
        /**
         * @var string
         * @ORM\Column(length=50)
         */
        private $nome;

        /**
         * @var string
         * @ORM\Column(length=3)
         */
        private $sigla;

        /**
         * @return string
         */
        public function getNome()
        {
            return $this->nome;
        }

        /**
         * @param string $nome
         */
        public function setNome($nome)
        {
            $this->nome = $nome;
        }

        /**
         * @return string
         */
        public function getSigla()
        {
            return $this->sigla;
        }

        /**
         * @param string $sigla
         */
        public function setSigla($sigla)
        {
            $this->sigla = $sigla;
        }

        /**
         * Retrieve input filter
         *
         * @return InputFilterInterface
         */
        public function getInputFilter()
        {
            if (!$this->inputFilter) {
                $factory = new Factory();
                $this->inputFilter = $factory->createInputFilter([
                    "nome" => ["required" => true],
                    "sigla" => ["required" => true]
                ]);
            }
            return $this->inputFilter;
        }
    }
```

Both entities extend my superclass AbstractEntity:

```
<?php

    namespace Application\Entity;

    use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\MappedSuperclass;
    use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
    use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilterAwareInterface;
    use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilterInterface;

    /**
     * Class AbstractEntity
     * @package Application\Entity
     * @MappedSuperClass
     */
    abstract class AbstractEntity implements InputFilterAwareInterface
    {
        /**
         * @var int
         * @ORM\Id
         * @ORM\GeneratedValue
         * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
         */
        protected $id;

        /**
         * @var InputFilterAwareInterface
         */
        protected $inputFilter;

        /**
         * @return int
         */
        public function getId()
        {
            return $this->id;
        }

        /**
         * @param int $id
         */
        public function setId($id)
        {
            $this->id = $id;
        }

        /**
         * @param InputFilterInterface $inputFilter
         * @return InputFilterAwareInterface
         * @throws \Exception
         */
        public function setInputFilter(InputFilterInterface $inputFilter)
        {
            throw new \Exception("Método não utilizado");
        }
    }
```

My HTML inputs are rendered as it follows:

```
<input name="cidade[nome]" class="form-control" value="" type="text">
<select name="cidade[estado][id]" class="form-control">
    <option value="3">Bahia</option>
    <option value="2">Espírito Santo</option>
    <option value="1">Minas Gerais</option>
    <option value="9">Pará</option>
</select>
```

Each `option` above is an Estado Entity retrieved from database. My POST data comes as the following example:

```
[
    "cidade" => [
        "nome" => "Test",
        "estado" => [
            "id" => 3
        ]
    ]
]
```

On Zend Form's `isValid()` method, this POST data is automatically converted to the target Entities, which makes me crash on this Doctrine issue. How do I move on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should bind an object to your form and use the Doctrine Hydrator. In the form the field names should exactly match that of the Entity. So `Entity#name` is `Form#name`.

With Separation of Concerns I'm absolutely against placing the InputFilter for an Entity within the Entity itself. As such, I'll give you an example with everything separated, if you decide to mash it back together, that's up to you.

#### AbstractEntity for ID

```
/**
 * @ORM\MappedSuperclass
 */
abstract class AbstractEntity
{
    /**
     * @var int
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    protected $id;
    // getter/setter
}
```

#### Cicade Entity

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Cidade extends AbstractEntity
{
    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(length=50)
     */
    protected $nome; // Changed to 'protected' so can be used in child classes - if any

    /**
     * @var Estado
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Estado", cascade={"persist", "detach"}) // persist added
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_estado", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $estado;

    // getters/setters
}
```

#### Estado Entity

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Estado extends AbstractEntity
{
    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(length=50)
     */
    protected $nome;

    //getters/setters
}
```

---

So, above is the Entity setup for [Many to One - Uni-direction](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-one-unidirectional) relation.

You want to manage this, easily, with forms. So we need to create InputFilters for both.

Having InputFilters **separately** from the Entity allows us to *nest* them. This in turn allows us to create structured and nested forms.

For example, you could create a new Estado on-the-fly. If this were a bi-directional relation, you could create multiple Cicade Entity objects on-the-fly from/during the creation of Estado.

First: InputFilters. In the spirit of abstraction, which you started with your Entities, let's do that here as well:

---

#### AbstractDoctrineInputFilter

[source AbstractDoctrineInputFilter](https://github.com/rkeet/zf-doctrine-form/blob/master/src/InputFilter/AbstractDoctrineInputFilter.php) & [source AbstractDoctrineFormInputFilter](https://github.com/rkeet/zf-doctrine-form/blob/master/src/InputFilter/AbstractDoctrineFormInputFilter.php)

This gives a nice clean setup and a requirement to fulfill. I'm glossing over the more complex elements added in the source files, feel free to look those up though.

Both objects (Estado & Cicade) require an ObjectManager (they're Doctrine entities after all), so I'm assuming you might have more. The below should come in handy.

```
<?php
namespace Application\InputFilter;

use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager;
use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilter;

abstract class AbstractInputFilter extends InputFilter
{
    /**
     * @var ObjectManager
     */
    protected $objectManager;

    /**
     * AbstractFormInputFilter constructor.
     *
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function __construct(array $options)
    {
        // Check if ObjectManager|EntityManager for FormInputFilter is set
        if (isset($options['object_manager']) && $options['object_manager'] instanceof ObjectManager) {
            $this->setObjectManager($options['object_manager']);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Init function
     */
    public function init()
    {
        $this->add(
            [
                'name' => 'id',
                'required' => false, // Not required when adding - should also be in route when editing and bound in controller, so just additional
                'filters' => [
                    ['name' => ToInt::class],
                ],
                'validators' => [
                    ['name' => IsInt::class],
                ],
            ]
       );

        // If CSRF validation has not been added, add it here
        if ( ! $this->has('csrf')) {
            $this->add(
                [
                    'name'       => 'csrf',
                    'required'   => true,
                    'filters'    => [],
                    'validators' => [
                        ['name' => Csrf::class],
                    ],
                ]
            );
        }
    }

    // getters/setters for ObjectManager
}
```

#### Estado InputFilter

```
class EstadoInputFilter extends AbstractInputFilter
{
    public function init()
    {
        parent::init();

        $this->add(
            [
                'name'        => 'nome', // <-- important, name matches entity property
                'required'    => true,
                'allow_empty' => true,
                'filters'     => [
                    ['name' => StringTrim::class],
                    ['name' => StripTags::class],
                    [
                        'name'    => ToNull::class,
                        'options' => [
                            'type' => ToNull::TYPE_STRING,
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
                'validators'  => [
                    [
                        'name'    => StringLength::class,
                        'options' => [
                            'min' => 2,
                            'max' => 255,
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
            ]
        );
    }
}
```

#### Cicade InputFilter

```
class EstadoInputFilter extends AbstractInputFilter
{
    public function init()
    {
        parent::init(); // Adds the CSRF

        $this->add(
            [
                'name'        => 'nome', // <-- important, name matches entity property
                'required'    => true,
                'allow_empty' => true,
                'filters'     => [
                    ['name' => StringTrim::class],
                    ['name' => StripTags::class],
                    [
                        'name'    => ToNull::class,
                        'options' => [
                            'type' => ToNull::TYPE_STRING,
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
                'validators'  => [
                    [
                        'name'    => StringLength::class,
                        'options' => [
                            'min' => 2,
                            'max' => 255,
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
            ]
        );

        $this->add(
            [
                'name'     => 'estado',
                'required' => true,
            ]
        );
    }
}
```

So. Now we have 2 InputFilters, based on an AbstractInputFilter.

`EstadoInputFilter` filters just the `nome` property. Add additional if you want ;)

`CicadeInputFilter` filters the `nome` property and has a required `estado` field.

The names match those of the Entity definition in the respective Entity classes.

Just to be complete, below is the `CicadeForm`, take what you need to create the `EstadoForm`.

```
class CicadeForm extends Form
{

    /**
     * @var ObjectManager
     */
    protected $objectManager;

    /**
     * AbstractFieldset constructor.
     *
     * @param ObjectManager $objectManager
     * @param string        $name Lower case short class name
     * @param array         $options
     */
    public function __construct(ObjectManager $objectManager, string $name, array $options = [])
    {
        parent::__construct($name, $options);

        $this->setObjectManager($objectManager);
    }

    public function init()
    {
        $this->add(
            [
                'name'     => 'nome',
                'required' => true,
                'type'     => Text::class,
                'options'  => [
                    'label' => _('Nome',
                ],
            ]
        );

        // @link: https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineModule/blob/master/docs/form-element.md
        $this->add(
            [
                'type'       => ObjectSelect::class,
                'required'   => true,
                'name'       => 'estado',
                'options'    => [
                    'object_manager'     => $this->getObjectManager(),
                    'target_class'       => Estado::class,
                    'property'           => 'id',
                    'display_empty_item' => true,
                    'empty_item_label'   => '---',
                    'label'              => _('Estado'),
                    'label_attributes'   => [
                        'title' => _('Estado'),
                    ],
                    'label_generator'    => function ($targetEntity) {
                        /** @var Estado $targetEntity */
                        return $targetEntity->getNome();
                    },
                ],
            ]
        );

        //Call parent initializer. Check in parent what it does.
        parent::init();
    }

    /**
     * @return ObjectManager
     */
    public function getObjectManager() : ObjectManager
    {
        return $this->objectManager;
    }

    /**
     * @param ObjectManager $objectManager
     *
     * @return AbstractDoctrineFieldset
     */
    public function setObjectManager(ObjectManager $objectManager) : AbstractDoctrineFieldset
    {
        $this->objectManager = $objectManager;
        return $this;
    }
}
```

---

#### Config

Now that the classes are there, how to use them? **Slap 'em together with module config!**

In your `module.config.php` file, add this config:

```
'form_elements'   => [
    'factories' => [
        CicadeForm::class => CicadeFormFactory::class,
        EstadoForm::class => EstadoFormFactory::class,

        // If you create separate Fieldset classes, this is where you register those
    ],
],
'input_filters'   => [
    'factories' => [
        CicadeInputFilter::class => CicadeInputFilterFactory::class,
        EstadoInputFilter::class => EstadoInputFilterFactory::class,

        // If you register Fieldsets in form_elements, their InputFilter counterparts go here
    ],
],
```

From this config we read we need a Factory for both the Form and for the InputFilter of a set.

#### Below the `CicadeInputFilterFactory`

```
class CicadeInputFilterFactory implements FactoryInterface
{
    /**
     * @param ContainerInterface $container
     * @param string             $requestedName
     * @param array|null         $options
     *
     * @return CicadeInputFilter
     * @throws \Psr\Container\ContainerExceptionInterface
     * @throws \Psr\Container\NotFoundExceptionInterface
     */
    public function __invoke(ContainerInterface $container, $requestedName, array $options = null)
    {
        /** @var ObjectManager|EntityManager $objectManager */
        $objectManager = $this->setObjectManager($container->get(EntityManager::class));

        return new CicadeInputFilter(
            [
                'object_manager' => objectManager,
            ]
        );
    }
}
```

#### Matching `CicadeFormFactory`

```
class CicadeFormFactory implements FactoryInterface
{
    /**
     * @param ContainerInterface $container
     * @param string             $requestedName
     * @param array|null         $options
     *
     * @return CicadeForm
     * @throws \Psr\Container\ContainerExceptionInterface
     * @throws \Psr\Container\NotFoundExceptionInterface
     */
    public function __invoke(ContainerInterface $container, $requestedName, array $options = null) : CicadeForm
    {
        $inputFilter = $container->get('InputFilterManager')->get(CicadeInputFilter::class);

        // Here we creazte a new Form object. We set the InputFilter we created earlier and we set the DoctrineHydrator. This hydrator can work with Doctrine Entities and relations, so long as data is properly formatted when it comes in from front-end.
        $form = $container->get(CicadeForm::class);
        $form->setInputFilter($inputFilter);
        $form->setHydrator(
            new DoctrineObject($container->get(EntityManager::class))
        );
        $form->setObject(new Cicade());

        return $form;
    }
}
```

---

### Massive preparation done, time to use it

Specific `EditController` to Edit an existing `Cicade` Entity

```
class EditController extends AbstractActionController // (Zend's AAC)
{
    /**
     * @var CicadeForm
     */
    protected $cicadeForm;

    /**
     * @var ObjectManager|EntityManager
     */
    protected $objectManager;

    public function __construct(
        ObjectManager $objectManager, 
        CicadeForm $cicadeForm
    ) {
        $this->setObjectManager($objectManager);
        $this->setCicadeForm($cicadeForm);
    }

    /**
     * @return array|Response
     * @throws ORMException|Exception
     */
    public function editAction()
    {
        $id = $this->params()->fromRoute('id', null);

        if (is_null($id)) {

            $this->redirect()->toRoute('home'); // Do something more useful instead of this, like notify of id received from route
        }

        /** @var Cicade $entity */
        $entity = $this->getObjectManager()->getRepository(Cicade::class)->find($id);

        if (is_null($entity)) {

            $this->redirect()->toRoute('home'); // Do something more useful instead of this, like notify of not found entity
        }

        /** @var CicadeForm $form */
        $form = $this->getCicadeForm();
        $form->bind($entity); // <-- This here is magic. Because we overwrite the object from the Factory with an existing one. This pre-populates the form with value and allows us to modify existing one. Assumes we got an entity above.

        /** @var Request $request */
        $request = $this->getRequest();
        if ($request->isPost()) {
            $form->setData($request->getPost());

            if ($form->isValid()) {
                /** @var Cicade $cicade */
                $cicade = $form->getObject();

                $this->getObjectManager()->persist($cicade);

                try {
                    $this->getObjectManager()->flush();
                } catch (Exception $e) {

                    throw new Exception('Could not save. Error was thrown, details: ', $e->getMessage());
                }

                $this->redirect()->toRoute('cicade/view', ['id' => $entity->getId()]);
            }
        }

        return [
            'form'               => $form,
            'validationMessages' => $form->getMessages() ?: '',
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @return CicadeForm
     */
    public function getCicadeForm() : CicadeForm
    {
        return $this->cicadeForm;
    }

    /**
     * @param CicadeForm $cicadeForm
     *
     * @return EditController
     */
    public function setCicadeForm(CicadeForm $cicadeForm) : EditController
    {
        $this->cicadeForm = $cicadeForm;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return ObjectManager|EntityManager
     */
    public function getObjectManager() : ObjectManager
    {
        return $this->objectManager;
    }

    /**
     * @param ObjectManager|EntityManager $objectManager
     *
     * @return EditController
     */
    public function setObjectManager(ObjectManager $objectManager) : EditController
    {
        $this->objectManager = $objectManager;
        return $this;
    }
}
```

---

So, felt like giving a really expanded answer. Covers the whole thing really.

If you have any questions about the above, let me know ;-)

Comment: As a side-note - Created the above answer form working elements of projects mashed together. If you copy/paste it, there might be errors as I didn't create full setup to replicate issue, but you should be able to figure them out in short order if you create/use this setup.

Comment: Not only gave me the brief explanation about DoctrineObject hydrator, which is my direct solution, but brought a whole context with rich details! Thanks!